# Обработка NULL значений

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Цель:

Реализовать многотабличный запрос с возможностью фильтрации и поиска через параметры 
Исключить сортировку по пустым столбцам

---

### Суть проблемы

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4505217) - 12.0.5223.6 (X64)
May 26 2019 20:36:50
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Вот запрос 
Я извинюсь за названия полей и таблиц, это не моих рук дело

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(t.NomerKarty,'-')                    AS NomerKarty,
o.Name,
f.Id,
f.FIO,
ti.DataVydachiKarty,
ti. DataIzjyatiyaKarty,
ISNULL(ti.StatusKarty,'-')                  AS StatusKarty,
ISNULL (ti.LimitKartyLMes,'-')              AS LimitKartyLMes
--Подключение основных таблиц
FROM ZayavkaNaVydachuToplivnoyKar           AS z
LEFT JOIN ToplivnayaKarta                   AS t ON z.ToplivnayaKarta = t.id
LEFT JOIN ToplivnayaKarta_InformaciyaO      AS ti ON t.id = ti.id
--Подключение справочников
INNER JOIN [FizicheskieLica]                AS f ON f.Id = z.FIOSotrudnika
INNER JOIN [MyLegalPerson]                  AS o ON o.Id = z.Organizaciya
--Условия отбора
WHERE ti.DataVydachiKarty >= @DataVydachi
        ti.DataVydachiKarty BETWEEN (SELECT ISNULL(@DataVydachi, min(ti.DataVydachiKarty))
                                    FROM ToplivnayaKarta_InformaciyaO ti 
                                    GROUP BY ti.DataVydachiKarty) 
                                    AND  
                                    (SELECT ISNULL(@DataVydachi, max(ti.DataVydachiKarty))
                                    FROM ToplivnayaKarta_InformaciyaO ti 
                                    GROUP BY ti.DataVydachiKarty)
                                    AND
        ti.DataIzjyatiyaKarty BETWEEN (SELECT ISNULL(@DataIzjyatiya, min(ti.DataIzjyatiyaKarty)) 
                                    FROM ToplivnayaKarta_InformaciyaO ti 
                                    GROUP BY ti.DataIzjyatiyaKarty)
                                    AND 
                                    (SELECT ISNULL(@DataIzjyatiya, max(ti.DataIzjyatiyaKarty)) 
                                    FROM ToplivnayaKarta_InformaciyaO ti 
                                    GROUP BY ti.DataIzjyatiyaKarty)
 {IF {$Organizaciya} <> null } 
    AND o.Id =  @Organizaciya
{END IF}
{IF {$FIO} <> null }
    AND f.Id =  @FIO
{END IF}
 {IF {$NomerKarty} <> null }
    AND t.id =  @NomerKarty
{END IF}
{IF {$Status} <> null }
    AND ti.StatusKarty =  @Status
{END IF}
```

Суть проблемы в том, что на данный момент большинство записей в таблице имеют NULL значение в том числе и `ti.DataVydachiKarty` `ti. DataIzjyatiyaKarty`
Проблема возникает в блоке `WHERE`, а конкретно в конструкциях `BETWEEN AND`, когда через них проходят абсолютно пустые значения столбцов запрос функционирует неправильно выдавая пустою таблицу

---

### Что я пробовал

1. В под запросе, в конструкции `BETWEEN AND` вы можете наблюдать функцию `min(ti.DataVydachiKarty)` или `max(ti.DataVydachiKarty)`, аналогично для других под запросов, не помогло ведь дат то нет
2. Заместо конструкций `min(ti.DataVydachiKarty)` или `max(ti.DataVydachiKarty)` указывал минимальную и максимальную дату, который позволяет тип данных т.е. `0001-01-01` и `9999-12-31`
3. В блоке `WHERE` дополнительно указывал условие:

```
WHERE 
ti.DataVydachiKarty IS NOT NULL AND ti.DataIzjyatiyaKarty IS NOT NULL AND
ti.DataVydachiKarty BETWEEN ... AND ... AND 
ti.DataIzjyatiyaKarty BETWEEN ... AND ...
```

К сожалению это тоже не помогло

4. Эксперименты в блоке `SELECT`, я использовал `ISNULL(ti.DataVydachiKarty, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))` аналогично для `ti.DataIzjyatiyaKarty`
   Но это не корректно
   `введите сюда код`
5. Некоторые другие незначительные правки, результат которых я уже не помню

---

upd: Объедение таблиц `LEFT JOIN` будет заменено на `INNER JOIN`, так как пустых значений быть не может, следовательно и этой проблемы тоже, но на данный момент она есть

Comment: 1) Указывайте точно СУБД, включая версию. 2) Если используется LEFT JOIN, то все ограничения по присоединяемой таблице должны располагаться не во WHERE, а в ON. 3) Если поле может быть NULL, то конвертируйте его в соответствующее константное значение функцией COALESCE(). 4) "upd:" - неясно к чему, ибо одно с другим никак не связано.

Comment: я-что то вообще не понимяю смысла этих between. Если дата нулл, то берете дату от минимума до максимама. И зачем это надо? если битвина этого не будет, то даты все равно будут от мин до макс, плюс пустые если есть. обычное условия вида `(@dataVydachi IS NULL or (ti.dataVydachi >= @dataVydachi) )` не подойдет тут?

Comment: @teran К сожалению смысл этих between состоит в том, что у нас должно быть одно обязательное условие, что бы условия ниже могли работать т.к. они начинаются с AND, далее я правильно понимаю, что если входящий параметр `@dataVydachi IS NULL` то отбор по этому параметру будет исключен? Я подредактировал цель вопроса

Comment: одно обязательное условие можно сделать `1=1`

Comment: @Akina Заменять значение в столбцах, с которыми у меня проблема, будет не корректно, там должны быть даты, но не минимальную, не максимальную, не текущую я поставить не могу, потому что их там и не может быть без самой записи

Comment: @teran Ну или вашу конструкцию, если это конечно же работает

Comment: *Заменять значение в столбцах, с которыми у меня проблема, будет не корректно* Это Вы сейчас о чём? я лично про замену значений в таблицах вообще ни полслова... Я имел в виду нечто типа `WHERE t1.column >= COALESCE(t2.column, t1.column)`.

Comment: @Akina Хорошо, я попробую

Comment: Но по сути никакой разницы с вариантом от @teran нет.

Comment: Могу посоветовать фундаментальную статью: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: @Akina Помогло, перенес условие в блок ON после JOIN и использовал данную конструкцию `WHERE t1.column >= COALESCE(t2.column, t1.column)`  Спасибо